# I Can't find network connection in Xubuntu xfce desktop environment

Tags: network-manager, xfce

In unity I used to run `system settings->network` to establish a DSL connection with username and password. I've switched to xfce for better performance. Now the problem is that I can't find such a thing in xfce.

In terminal I typed: `nm-connection-editor` command, but it's not installed. I removed Unity from Ubuntu software center. Is there a way to make Internet up and running as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open a terminal and install network-manager-gnome with

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

You should get the *nm-connection-editor* after it.

Edit: True, so if you can use another computer (I hope you're not writing here from your phone ^^), download `network-manager-gnome.deb` and install it with this:

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

Comment: I don't have an Internet connection. I need to provide username and password for DSL to connect to internet. So using apt-get install fails!